# Apache crashes in a large foreach loop on an associative array in PHP

Tags: php, crash, foreach, associative-array, phpexcel

**EDIT**: In response to Robus' answer I tried to run the PHP script from command line. This is the result:

[image: CLI crash]

But interestingly; an echo statement that was located **after** the `foreach` loop in my code output it's text to the console window. Thus I can only assume that CLI crashes at the conclusion of / after running the script.

---

I have a script which function is to load all rows from an XLSX file into a MySQL table. I am using PHPExcel for this. I wrote the function `loadFromXLS` to load the data from the XLSX file and return a two dimensional array with the data. In this particular case that means 3100 rows and 29 columns.

This is the function:

```
function loadFromXLS($filepath)
{
    $retval = array();
    $cols = array();
    $rownum = 0;

    $reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($filepath);
    $reader->setReadDataOnly(true);

    $phpObject = $reader->load($filepath);
    $sheet = $phpObject->getActiveSheet();

    foreach($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row)
    {
        $celliterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        $celliterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
        $cellnum = 0;

        foreach($celliterator as $cell)
        {
            if($rownum === 0)
            {
                $cols[$cellnum] = $cell->getValue();
            }
            else
            {
                if(is_array($retval[$rownum-1]))
                    $retval[$rownum-1] += array($cols[$cellnum] => $cell->getValue());
                else
                    $retval[$rownum-1] = array($cols[$cellnum] => $cell->getValue());
            }

            $cellnum++;
        }

        $rownum++;
    }

    unset($reader, $phpObject, $sheet);

    return $retval;
}
```

The top row of the file is the column names.

In any case, I have confirmed that it loads the data correctly by `var_dump`ing the first few rows and checking the array length.

This is the problem. As soon as I add this line:

```
foreach($data as $i => $row) {};
```

Apache simply crashes when it gets to that point:

[image: Apache crash]

**So what's up with that? Can't PHP handle loops through large associative arrays? Any explanatory answers would be appreciated. Please comment if there is additional information I can provide**

---

*I'm running XAMPP on Windows 7, Intel i5 processor, 4GB RAM. I have increased `memory_limit` in php.ini to 512MB which is more than enough (It used to give me a memory error when it was set to 128MB). This script includes PHPExcel.php and dBug.php. The two dimensional array is only filled with strings, no funky PHPExcel datatypes.*

*I'm running PHP version 5.3.1*

*Loaded modules: core mod_win32 mpm_winnt http_core mod_so mod_actions mod_alias mod_asis mod_auth_basic mod_auth_digest mod_authn_default mod_authn_file mod_authz_default mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_cgi mod_dav mod_dav_fs mod_dav_lock mod_dir mod_env mod_headers mod_include mod_info mod_isapi mod_log_config mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_ssl mod_status mod_autoindex_color mod_php5 mod_perl mod_apreq2*

[phpinfo() screenshot](http://i76.photobucket.com/albums/j37/dahwan/Capture-6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your php installation..

Comment: Would you care to elaborate? Is this a known issue? I'm using PHP 5.3. I'll check for the exact version and add it to the question

Comment: i'm not aware of any such known issue, Codemonkey.  It's probably sound advice, though.

Comment: if it crashes 95% of the time is due to some PHP bugs.. If I was you I'd try to update php version

Comment: Well it turns out you were right. I upgraded to PHP 5.3.5 and the problem went away. Such a boring result :-P Now I won't be able to fix this problem on older PHP installations

Comment: Next time we may try to restart Windows first.

Answer (score 2):

Try omitting apache altogether and just run the script from command line, see what happens

Comment: Do you really have to add all the data to mysql at once, or can you just add each row individually and discard data as you go? We could at least see if it dies at setup phase or at some particular entry.

Comment: I see that as irrelevant since PHP **should** be able to handle such a string (500 000 characters or so) extremely easily. And in the cases where it isn't, it **should** output a managed understandable error message, not crash. Therefore I would like to get to the bottom of this, since in the future I might have a similar problem where your solution isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add some memory to PHP.
2. It's not too lucky to return a big array in PHP. You should use instead:

   ```
   function loadFromXLS($filepath,&$retval) {
     ...
   }
   ```

   Then you should remove *$retval = array();* and put it before the call of this funct.

Comment: I have now set the memory limit to 1024M. Loading the XML file required less than 256M. I also changed the function to use pointer input, but the program still crashes. I am now convinced that the problem is not due to lack of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Simply unsetting $phpObject and $sheet will have no effect whatsoever. These contain cyclic object references, which don't clean-up well in PHP, so they will not be unset unless you break those references first. This can be done using

```
$phpObject->disconnectWorksheets();
```

as described in section 4.3 of the developer documentation ("Clearing a Workbook from memory").

Get rid of the iterator loops to populate your array, and use PHPExcel's built-in method.

```
return $sheet->toArray();
```

You can also pass the following arguments to the toArray() method:

```
* @param  mixed    $nullValue            Value returned in the array entry if a cell doesn't exist
* @param  boolean  $calculateFormulas    Should formulas be calculated?
* @param  boolean  $formatData           Should formatting be applied to cell values?
* @param  boolean  $returnCellRef        False - Return a simple array of rows and columns indexed by number counting from zero
*                                        True - Return rows and columns indexed by their actual row and column IDs
```

It won't give you quite the associative array that your own loops do, but it will be faster, and more memory efficient that your loops.

Comment: That's sort of odd, seeing as my code is almost a direct copy from the PHPExcel examples. In any case, I concluded earlier that my problem isn't caused by lack of memory. Also, it's insanely hard to find stuff in PHPExcel's documentation, so I'm sure it would be a nightmare to figure out how to return the data as an associative array with values assigned to variables with the correct column names.
But other than that, thanks for the optimization tip.

Comment: I apologise that the documentation isn't as easy to try and find your way around as you might like (it's surprising how many people don't even find the documentation)... but there are limits to what one man can do in his free time.

Comment: I assume you're the author then :-) I meant no offence. Most API or library documentations is in the shape of a class reflection document in HTML on the internet. The upsides of this is that every function is documented and easy to find. I would highly recommend you do that. In addition, the entire documentation would create itself (With help from a third-party application of course) using your comments. I assume you know this already of course :-P Just pointing out how useful it would be. (And thank you for writing PHPExcel!)

Comment: While documentation isn't available on the internet, full API documentation is provided in the production downloads, built using PHPDocumentor... in the /Documentation/API directory, so every method is documented... so yes, I am aware of this

Comment: Another possibility... could Apache be timing out before the script has finished executing? Typically, Apache has a 5 minute timeout limit

Comment: All such events should and do get reported by PHP through the browser window. I upgraded to PHP 5.3.5 and the problem disappeared, which is unfortunate since it makes this problem very hard to solve. In a situation like this, where I didn't have access to upgrade PHP, what would I do? But thanks for helping me find the PHPDocumentor documentation :-) I can understand why people don't find it